# TO generate serial number in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table : xyz

```
id    |survey_id | submitted  | username
---------------------------------------
  155 | 8        | 1537276842 | 2
  156 | 8        | 1537276842 | 2
  157 | 8        | 1537276877 | 2
```

I run a below query in database :

```
SELECT DISTINCT case when result.aid < result.bid then result.aid else result.bid end as original, case when result.aid < result.bid then result.bid else result.aid end as duplicate FROM (SELECT a.id AS aid, b.id AS bid, a.submitted AS asubmitted, b.submitted AS bsubmitted FROM xyz AS a INNER JOIN xyz AS b ON (a.username = b.username AND a.survey_id = b.survey_id) WHERE a.id != b.id AND (abs(a.submitted - b.submitted) <= 300) ORDER BY a.id) AS result
```

And 
get :

```
original     |duplicate
--------------------
  155        | 157
  155        | 156
  156        | 157
```

After that I want to add serial number in first column then I executed given below query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number, 
    case when result.aid < result.bid then result.aid 
      else result.bid end as original, 
    case when result.aid < result.bid then result.bid 
      else result.aid end as duplicate 
FROM (SELECT a.id AS aid, b.id AS bid, a.submitted AS asubmitted, b.submitted AS bsubmitted 
      FROM xyz AS a 
      INNER JOIN xyz AS b ON (a.username = b.username AND a.survey_id = b.survey_id), 
      (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS result 
WHERE a.id != b.id AND (abs(a.submitted - b.submitted) <= 300) 
ORDER BY a.id) AS result
```

And 
**get:**

```
row_number   |original     |duplicate
---------------------------------------
  1          | 155         | 157
  2          | 155         | 156
  3          | 156         | 157
  4          | 155         | 156
  5          | 155         | 157
  6          | 156         | 157
```

So I have an issue why it will be getting double after adding serial number to my query . I need result like below format

```
row_number   |original     |duplicate
---------------------------------------
  1          | 155         | 157
  2          | 155         | 156
  3          | 156         | 157
```

Comment: I have removed incompatible tags & tag the only DBMS which you are really using.

Comment: Can you format your SQL so it's not all in one line please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to number the rows. For this wrap what you get as the latest correct result in another subquery, so making it something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT case when result.aid < result.bid then result.aid else result.bid end as original, case when result.aid < result.bid then result.bid else result.aid end as duplicate 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT a.id AS aid, b.id AS bid, a.submitted AS asubmitted, b.submitted AS bsubmitted 
        FROM xyz AS a 
        INNER JOIN xyz AS b ON (a.username = b.username AND a.survey_id = b.survey_id) 
        WHERE a.id != b.id AND (abs(a.submitted - b.submitted) <= 300) 
        ORDER BY a.id
    ) AS result) AS resultresult;
```

and then add your sequence to it:

```
SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row, resultresult.* FROM (SELECT DISTINCT case when result.aid < result.bid then result.aid else result.bid end as original, case when result.aid < result.bid then result.bid else result.aid end as duplicate 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT a.id AS aid, b.id AS bid, a.submitted AS asubmitted, b.submitted AS bsubmitted 
        FROM xyz AS a 
        INNER JOIN xyz AS b ON (a.username = b.username AND a.survey_id = b.survey_id) 
        WHERE a.id != b.id AND (abs(a.submitted - b.submitted) <= 300) 
        ORDER BY a.id
    ) AS result) AS resultresult , (SELECT @row := 0) r;
```

It produces correct

```
1   155 156
2   155 157
3   156 157
```

result for me.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can simply change your join to get the results you're after:

```
CREATE TABLE AAU.xyz
(
id INTEGER,
survey_id INTEGER,
submitted INTEGER,
username INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO AAU.xyz VALUES (155,8,1537276842,2),
(156,8,1537276842,2),
(157,8,1537276877,2);


SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.username ORDER BY a.id) AS "row_number", a.id, b.id
FROM AAU.xyz a
LEFT JOIN AAU.xyz b ON (a.username = b.username AND a.survey_id = b.survey_id) 
WHERE a.id < b.id
```