# MySQL stored procedure how to generate a new auto_increment?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I have a procedures like this on MySQL

```
SELECT t.name AS cat_name , f.id AS id_food 
FROM food AS f, categories AS t
WHERE f.quantity > 0 
AND t.id = f.id_cat 
ORDER BY t.name
```

When I execute it show a table

```
| cat_name | id_food |
| -------- | -------------|
| Seafood  | 1            |
| Seafood  | 3            |
| Seafood  | 5            |
| Beef     | 2            |
| Beef     | 16           |
| Special  | 7            |
```

Was wondering is there anything to make this table generate a new **auto_increment id field** in front of it?

This is what i want it to look like when execute

```
| new_id  | cat_name | id_food |
|----     |------    | -----   |
| 1       | Seafood  | 1       |
| 2       | Seafood  | 3       |
| 3       | Seafood  | 5       |
| 4       | Beef     | 2       |
| 5       | Beef     | 16      |
| 6       | Special  | 7       |
```

Comment: Take a look at the JOIN Syntax in the Manual

Comment: What's your MySQL version?

Comment: check following link, are you looking for serial numbers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404085/to-generate-serial-number-in-mysql

Comment: Please add categories.ID to the result of your query,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your MySQL version support `ROW_NUMBER` + window function you can try this.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.name)new_id
       t.name AS cat_name ,
       f.id AS id_food 
FROM food AS f 
INNER JOIN categories AS t 
ON t.id = f.id_cat
WHERE f.quantity > 0 
ORDER BY t.name
```

Comment: It showed me this error https://imgur.com/a/JjmhfVj
Does this mean MySQL doesnt support ROW_NUMBER()? Weird since my version is 10.1.36-MariaDB

Comment: 'MariaDB starting with 10.2
Window functions were first introduced in MariaDB 10.2.0.' is upgrading an option? ps mariadb is not mysql please add mariadb tag and correct your question.

Comment: Thanks it worked, just updated it to ver 10.4, always thought mariadb and mysql were the same thing. Thank u